# How to autosize datagridview rows to get rid of blank gray areas

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, autosize

Hello I have a vbnet windows forms application and I'm looking for a simple way of deleting the blank areas of a datagridview. I know there is a simple way of doing this for columns using the

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
```

It seems sort of strange to me that there isn't a similar way of dong this for the rows. Does anyone know of a simple way of fixing this issue? I greatly appreciate any help or suggestions you may offer.

[image]

Comment: @stackechange12 did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want empty rows in your grid, do not load them in the grid.

Grids are usually filled by setting its' DataSource property.  This may be anything that implements IList, and a few other things like a DataTable/DataSet.  If you dont want them in the grid, dont put them in the object that you used as your DataSource.

If you used some type of list the implements INotifyCollectionChanged, like an ObservableCollection or BindingSource, you can `Remove` the items after they are added.

Comment: This answer does not apply now that your question was edited.

Comment: No I'm not talking about empty rows, here I'll add a screen shot. Its the blank area of the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of that "Blank" area, you need to resize the grid.